# How does rails know if it runs under a subpath?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

I want to run a rails app on https://server.com/myapp/testing. If I say `redirect_to '/bla'`, I want it to redirect to `/myapp/testing/bla`. How do I tell rails, that it should prefix all paths with `/myapp/testing`?

I'running rails 5 and passenger with apache httpd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is said here in the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#deploy-to-a-subdirectory-relative-url-root), you can config your rails app to run in a subdirectory by adding this line in `config/application.rb`

```
config.relative_url_root = '/myapp/testing'
```

This will help rails to generate the appropriate routes.

You may also need to config your passenger config according to this [docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/#deploying-an-app-to-a-sub-uri-or-subdirectory)

Edit: As suggested by @le_me, `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` must be set for passenger to communicate the prefix to the rails app.

Comment: Sane advice, thank you. In my case the problem was probably a bug in devise. I fixed it by overwriting the redirect paths after sign_in and sign_out.

Anyway, I researched on my own and found out that there is an environment variable called `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT`, that rails uses to set `config.relative_url_root`. I guess that passenger uses this to communicate the prefix to the rails app, because for me it works without modifications to `config/application.rb`. If you could add this information to your answer I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: Hi @le_me, thank you for pointing out. I have got my answer updated. Sincerely.